# MarkLogic HTTP AppServer returns "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I executed the Self-paced Developer's XQuery class code for creating an HTTP AppService for 8030-world-leaders and placed `hello.xqy` in the root directory of the filesystem where it is suppossed to look. I get an "This site can’t be reached" error when I issue the URL `http://<fullservername>:8030/hello.xqy` in the browser. Where do I look for errors on the server? How do I troubleshoot this? Any pointers are helpful. I see that the Oracle-Linux server is listening on port 8030 when I issue `netstat -a |grep 8030`

Comment: Typo..URL that I used was http://fullhostname:8030/hello.xqy

Answer (score 1):

If you'd go to the MarkLogic Admin UI on port 8001, and open the Status tab on the landing page, your 8030-world-leaders app server should show up among the app servers. Check if it shows in red. If it shows red, it probably failed to claim port 8030 when it tried to initialize the app server. Simply go to the configure tab of that app server, pick a different, free port, maybe 8031, and save the change. MarkLogic will restart the app-server for you, and after that you should be able to connect to it on the new port without any further changes.

HTH!

Comment: It is not red. Also when I delete the 8030-world-leaders HTTP AppServer and netstat -a |grep 8030 does not show the row "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8030            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN". After I create the HTTP AppServer, it shows up in netstat -a. So, I am assuming it is able to run the HTTP service but I am thinking there should be some logs or something I can use to troubleshoot if the HTTP service is able to see my request.

Comment: If I do a wget, I get a message saying "Connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response.... 401 Unauthorized   Authorization failed."

Comment: Also, I have just one file in the root directory of HTTP server with following content: xquery version "1.0-ml";
"Hello World!"

Comment: Is there some authorization/security that I have to enable for the HTTP Service? The HTTP service root directory /marklogic/apps2 and the file hello.xqy have permissions for ‘daemon’ to read.

Comment: MarkLogic app servers use "basic", "basicdigest", "digest" or "application-level" security. For most of them, you'll need to provide a username and password. At this stage, just to make sure things are working, you might use the admin account that you set up when you installed MarkLogic.